# Prove $\operatorname{gcd}(a-1,a+1)$

Tags: divisibility

> Let $a$ be an integer. After looking at several examples, make a conjecture about the value of $\operatorname{gcd}(a-1,a+1)$ and prove it.

Ok. I found that:

- if $a$ is even, $\operatorname{gcd}(a-1,a+1)=1$;
- if $a$ is odd, $\operatorname{gcd}(a-1,a+1)=2$.

Is this conjecture right? Any advice to how to prove this conjecture?

Comment: It's right. Use $\gcd(x,y) = \gcd(x, y-x)$ to prove it.

Comment: gcd(a+1, a-1) = gcd(a+1, (a+1) - (a -1)) = gcd(a+1,2).  2 is prime.  gcd(2,m) = 2 if 2|m and gcd(2,m) = 1 if 2 doesn't divide m.

Answer (score 4):

Correct. Basically, just use the fact that $x-y$ is a multiple of $\gcd(x,y)$, i.e. $\gcd(x,y)|x-y$.

In both cases, $x-y=2$, so the gcd can only be 1 or 2.

Comment: Can I substitute like, $gcd(a-1,a+1)|(a-1)-(a+1)$ ?

Comment: Yes, definitely!

Comment: Ok, so if $a$ is odd,$2n+1$, then $gcd((a-1,a+1)=2$. Let $a=2n+1$, want to show $gcd(a-1,a+1)|(a-1)-(a+1)$. In the other words,$gcd(a-1,a+1)|-2$ ? I don't know.

Comment: Acutally gcd(a−1,a+1)|−2 is the same as gcd(a-1, a+1)|2. So gcd(a-1,a+1) = 1 or 2. If a is odd, then a-1 and a+1 are even, so 2|gcd(a-1,a+1), so gcd(a-1,a+1)=2. If a is even, then a-1 and a+1 are odd, so the gcd cannot be 2, so it must be 1.

Answer (score 1):

First, we are going to denote $p$ as the $gcd(a-1, a+1)$

This implies $$a-1 = pk, \ a+1 = pk'$$ with $k' > k$

Moreover $a+1 = (a-1)+2$. Thus $pk + 2 = pk' \Rightarrow p(k'-k) = 2$ with $k'-k \geq 1$ that implies that $0<p\leq 2$

Now you can see $p$ is 1 if $a$ is even and 2 if $a$ is odd

Answer (score 0):

If a number, in this case GCD(a-1,a+1), divides two numbers, a-1 and a+1, it divides their difference, namely 2. If a is odd, both numbers are even, so the answer is 2. If a is even, a+1 is odd, so the answer is 1.